# How to find sum of even numbers in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I am learning assembly on my own. I want to find sum of even numbers. However, it does not work, I can't understand why, it does not show any error.

my code is below

```
        mov ebx, 0;
        mov ESI, [arr]; 
        mov ECX, [arr_size];

    sumeven:
        push ebx;
       
        mov eax, dword ptr[ESI];
        mov ebx, 2;
        cdq
        idiv ebx;
        cmp edx, 0;
        je adding;
        


    adding: 
        pop ebx;
        add ebx, dword ptr[ESI];
        add ESI, 4;
        loop sumeven;


    mov result, ebx;
```

I am using inline assembly in c language.

Comment: Your code falls through into `adding` anyway.

Comment: why? 1%2=1 why it falls there?

Comment: What do you think happens after the `je`? The cpu continues to the next line. So in either case, you end up at `adding`.

Comment: Thanks I fixed.

Comment: It is unusual to use `idiv` just to check if divisible by 2, it is not done in real-life code. This assembly will not perform as good as similar C code. I hope you know it.

Comment: You might do it as `sum += ~((a[i]<<31) >> 31) & a[i]` to zero out odd elements.  That can vectorize with SSE or AVX as `vpslld xmm1, xmm0, 31` / `vpsrad xmm1, 31` (broadcast the low bit to all bits) / `vpandn xmm1,xmm0` / `vpaddd xmm7, xmm1`.  Then horizontal sum `xmm7` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you jump to the label *adding:* when the number is even, but when it is odd you fall through in that same label, so you always do the sum.
The correct code is:

```
    mov ebx, 0;
    mov esi, [arr]; 
    mov ecx, [arr_size];

    jecxz emptyarr

sumeven:
    push ebx;
    mov eax, [ESI];
    mov ebx, 2;
    cdq
    idiv ebx;
    cmp edx, 0;

    pop ebx;
    jne notadding;

    add ebx, dword ptr[ESI];

notadding:
    add esi, 4;
    loop sumeven;

emptyarr:
```

Another solution may be:

```
  cld                      ; clear string direction flag for "lods"
  
  xor   ebx, ebx;          ; fast clear ebx register: the even sum
  mov   esi, [arr];        ; load pointer to array into esi reg.
  mov   ecx, [arr_size];   ; load size of the array into ecx reg.

  jecxz EmptyArr           ; if empty array, terminate the routine

SumEven:
  lodsd                    ; mov eax,[esi], esi=esi+4
  test  eax, 1;            ; if less significant bit is 1, odd element
  jne   NotAdding          ; if odd element skip the sum

  add   ebx, eax;          ; add the element to the sum reg.

NotAdding:
  dec   ecx                ; ecx= ecx-1
  jnz   SumEven            ; if ecx<>0 go to SumEven

EmptyArr:
```

NOTE: if you use a 32-bit register, as EAX register, to move data to or from memory, for example: `mov eax, dword ptr [esi]` or `mov dword ptr [esi], eax`,
you don't need to specify the size of data with type cast "dword ptr".
You can simply write: `mov eax, [esi]` or `mov [esi], eax`.

Answer (score 0):

I added condition for not equal to 0, and it worked.

```
        cmp edx, 0;
        je adding;
        jne notequal;
    notequal:
    ---
```

Comment: That doesn't help, unless there's a `jmp` or something somewhere in the `---`.  If you instead replicated a `loop` instruction or something in that `---` block, it could fall through into `adding:` if you hit the loop exit there.   `jne notequal` / `notequal:` is always a NOP, it always falls through to `notequal`, so just adding that doesn't do anything.  So basically what you're showing in this answer is adding a NOP, and only vaguely hinting at whatever you did that actually worked (or happened to work for this data, if it involves an unsafe use of `loop`).

Answer (score -1):

sum of even numbers from 0 to 30

```
.model small

.stack 100h

.data

arrtxt db "the sum of even number 0 to 30 is : ",10,'$'

arr dw 8 dup('$')

num dw ?



.code

main proc

mov ax,@data

mov ds,ax




mov si,offset arr

mov  cx,0

mov dx,offset arrtxt

mov  ah,9  

int 21h

mov bx,2 

l1:

  cmp cx,30

  jg print

  mov ax,cx

  mov dx,0

  div bx

  cmp dx,0

  jz addition
  
  inc cx

  jmp l1


addition:

    add num,cx

    inc cx

    jmp l1


print:
    
mov cx,0

arrr:

    MOV AX,0

    mov ax,num

    mov bx,10

    cmp ax,0

    je getarr

    mov dx,0

    div bx

    add dx,48

    push dx

    mov num,ax

    inc cx

    jmp arrr

getarr:

    pop dx

    mov ah,2

    int 21h

    loop getarr



mov ah,4ch

int 21h

main endp

end main
```

Comment: Testing for even doesn't require `div`, just `test cl, 1` / `jnz not_even`.  Never use `div` when the divisor is a constant power of 2.  Also, aren't you just adding the odd integers from 1 to 29 in your `l1:` loop?  So you could just `add cx, 2` to skip the even numbers entirely.  The code in the question has an array of integers as input.  Your code has a weird `arr dw 8 dup('$')` and sets `si` to point to it, but you never store or load to it, without any comments to explain that that's for.  IDK why you'd want a 16-byte buffer filled with alternating `0` and `'$'` bytes anyway.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).